# how to get the sum of field 'size' from my database and print it in my php page

Tags: php, sql

I have a database with a table named "photos". In that table i have a column "size"(which is the size of the photos i had upload). I want to get the sum of these sizes and print the sum in my php page. Can anyone give me an example code(sql code in php code)..??

i have try this:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(ph_size) from photos";
$result= mysql_query($query,$con);
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>SUM(ph_size)</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
//echo $row;
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['SUM(ph_size)'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

but it doesnt work.

Comment: Start with [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html). You don't specify your RDBMS but I'll bet dollars to donuts it's MySQL.

Comment: love that Analogy Michael , dollars to donuts :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the sum function

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(p.size) AS sum_of_photos_sizes FROM `photos` p WHERE 1");
if (mysql_num_rows($result)){
$data=mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo 'Total size of photos: '.$data['sum_of_photos_sizes'];
}
```